# Will rooting my phone improve its battery life?

Tags: rooting, battery-life

I've had an HTC Desire HD with HTC Sense for about a year and I'm quite happy, except for the battery life. After upgrading to the latest version, it lasts about 24 hours with moderate/low usage.

I was wondering 2 things:

- If I root it, will i gain some significant battery life?
- After a phone is rooted, can it later be returned to the factory state?

I dont know much about rooting.

Comment: Your phone is most probably not running Android 3.0, as it was released only for tablets. Please check your settings if you'd like to figure out what version you are actually running (`Settings->About Phone`). Also, 24 hours of battery life is about typical for smartphones nowadays. What are you looking to get from the battery?

Comment: Android version is 2.3.5, but the version of HTC sense is 3.0, which kinda resembles the way it works on tablets

Comment: Depends on what you do with the root. You can underclock and get dramatically better battery life.

Comment: @eldarerathis 24 hours is what I would expect with high usage.  Moderate usage on my phone (An hour continuous at lunch, games while waiting for the train to/from work, and using it as my alarm clock, but rarely using it as a phone to talk on) gives me on average about 50 hours with Android 2.1 - you should probably also check that you don't have a runaway app that's draining some of the battery if that's what you expect to be average...

Comment: @Izkata: The Galaxy Nexus averages somewhere between 3.5 - 5 hours of screen on time for one charge. 24 hours or so is very typical of today's high-end smartphones, especially ones with larger screens and 4G networking. Based on the fact that you have Android 2.1 I'm going to guess your phone is not 4G capable and probably has lower screen/processor specs than, for example, a GNex. My typical usage could probably run for closer to 36-40 hours without charging, but I don't see a reason not to simply plug it in every night, anyway.

Comment: @Izkata: Granted, this also depends on how you define "light", "moderate" and "heavy" usage. I'd consider 1-2 hours of use a day near the low end. I typically use my phone ~3 hours per day, and I'd consider that "moderate" compared to others I know, but on LTE with a large screen it'll run the battery into the 30% range.

Comment: @eldarerathis Yes, I should have specified model, too: Samsung Galaxy S (Specifically, the AT&T version, the Captivate).  I included my definition of "moderate" in the previous comment so we'd have some sort of comparison.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way rooting can gain you battery time is if you can uninstall an app that's using a lot of power, and which you can't uninstall without rooting (i.e. it's something that shipped with the device). I don't know what is on your device, but judging from what I've seen on my Droid 3, there's not likely to be any noticeable change in battery life. On the plus side, if you root the device, you'll have the option to get rid of any junk that was pre-installed and thereby not have to see all the update notices for stuff that you'll never use and which wants more and more permissions with every update.

Comment: If you are just rooting (not flashing a custom OS), it is usually better to freeze the problem apps than removing. If the carrier/manufacturer releases an update for the device they check for these apps and if missing will fail to update.

Comment: Well, in the battery reports, none of the trash apps are on the top of the battery usage, so I guess I wont be getting any real advantage if I root.

Comment: @jlehenbauer 's answer below is more accurate. You will save battery life by reducing the clock speed and voltages and if possible also reducing the no. of actively functional cores in newer multi-core processors. All that can only be achieved by rooting and then using a kernel that supports these features.

Comment: @Dbugger Not completely true - some apps will hold a wakelock and prevent the CPU from sleeping.  Those won't show up in the battery usage list since they're not actually doing anything during that time.  _Finding_ those ones is in my experience quite difficult...

Comment: @Michael - I think you're forgetting the possibility to reduce the CPU clock frequency which can help battery life. Also, surely "Android System", "Android OS" and others could be tweaked in the custom ROM to improve life further?

Comment: @DanW - with most phones that I've seen, the biggest factors in battery life are how much you use it and how you have the screen brightness set. You can mess around with the cpu clock frequency and and tweak to your heart's content and you'll perhaps gain a percent or three, but unless that's your hobby, it's not worth the bother - it won't get you a meaningful increase in runtime.

Comment: @Michael - thanks. I use my phone mostly on standby, and so processes such as "Android System" and "Android OS" go to the top. I'm wondering if these may be lighter on a custom ROM such as 'Simplicity'. After all, how does my old phone last two weeks on a *smaller* battery? That's 25x longer than my current Galaxy I9000.

Answer (score 6):

If you choose to root your phone, there are several options as far as installing **custom ROMs** and/or **custom kernels**. Some of these allow you change the clock speed of your processor, the governor controlling the processor, and so on, which can all positively (or negatively) affect battery life. If you are already rooted, [ROM Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox&hl=en) gives some nice options as far as system manipulation that can help with battery life.

[Juice Defender Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.latedroid.ultimatejuice&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5sYXRlZHJvaWQudWx0aW1hdGVqdWljZSJd) also has some pretty cool options if you're root.

Answer (score -3):

rooting android saves up to 25% of battery compared to factory state.

I would suggest you use Kingo Android Root & framaroot.

Comment: Rooting has nothing to do with battery, root is equivalent of Administrator on Windows that has the privilege to do system wide changes. Bearing that in mind, can install custom kernels, apps that claim to "squeeze extra juice" from battery etc, with custom CPU governers etc, but really, from the viewpoint of root, your answer looks vague, why 25%, where did you get that from?  What's Kingo Android Root? What's framaroot? A linky or two would help with a brief summary of how to use it.

Comment: 83.4% of all statistics are made up. In other words, cite your source.